# Cannot get JavaScript password regex validation to work

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a user entered password. It can only be letters and numbers and I have to use the match method...even if it isn't the best way...I have to use match(). I am missing something to get the working properly. No number or special characters only letters. I do not know much about javascript.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function chkPwd() {
    var pwd = document.form1.pwd;
    var pwdMsg = document.getElementById('pwdMsg'); 

    regex = /[^a-zA-Z]/;
        var pwd1 = pwd.value;
        if(!pwd1.match(regex)) {
            pwdMsg.innerHTML = "Must contain letters only!"
            pwd.select();
            return;
        }else{ 
            pwdMsg.innerHTML = "";
        }
    }   
</script>
</head>

<body>
        <form name="form1" action="" method="post">


            <p> Password: <br>
                <input type="text" name="pwd" onchange="chkPwd()" />
                <span id="pwdMsg"></span></p>
            <p>
                <input type="button" value="chkPass" onclick="chkPwd()">
            </p>
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you defined `regex` but then used `regx` which appears to be undefined.

Comment: I'd imagine if you looked at your javascript console you should have seen the error.

Comment: Thanks @smerny I see the error in my console..like I said I don't know much about javascript. Which is why I came here to get help.

Comment: you keep modifying your question with the fixes... do you still have a problem?

Comment: yes. I still have the same problem. I only modified the problem because people kept pointing out my typo after I said that I saw it. So I fixed it. The problem is that when all letters are entered it doesn't pass validation...which it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue appears to be in this section of code.

```
regex = /[^a-zA-Z]/;
var pwd1 = pwd.value;
if(!pwd1.value.match(regx)) {
```

You are setting the `pwd1` to `pwd.value`, but then on the next line, you are accessing `pwd1.value`. This means that you are efficiently doing `pwd.value.value`. Additionally, you are using `regx` where you should use `regex`. Also, your if condition does not appear to need a `!` in it. I think you mean to do this.

```
regex = /[^a-zA-Z]/;
var pwd1 = pwd.value;
if(pwd1.match(regex)) {
```

Comment: This is close...however the error message still comes up when it is only letters still when it should be fine.

Comment: @floyd See updated answer. The `!` in the if statement is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want letters only you should use this regex:

```
^[A-Za-z]+$
```

If you want to have letters and numbers then use:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

Btw, as guys pointed out you are using `regx` instead of `regex`